# How to authenticate to the QnA Maker API through Azure Data Factory?

Tags: authentication, azure-data-factory, azure-qna-maker

I cannot find this in the documentation, what is the best way to authenticate to the QnA Maker API in Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) (essentially and HTTP call), as long as you set the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` as per the [QnA Maker REST API documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff) it should work.

There are examples of the request bodies, code samples, and a testing panel in the documentation I linked above.